# VSTO Outlook AddIn Deployment/Installer help on VS2015

Tags: vsto, visual-studio-2017, outlook-addin, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created a VSTO Outlook AddIn using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition. My development computer is 64bit Win10. I have created an installer (DVD) using InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition. I am able to run the intaller on 64bit OS successfully.
On 32bit OS I am getting error immediately after launching the installer "The installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your vendor"

Following are the 3 places where I could find he information regarding the processor/OS

```
VS Project -->Compile-->Platform  -->AnyCPU

VS Project -->Compile-->TargetCPU -->AnyCPU

InstallShieldProject--> (5)Define Setup Requirements and Actions -->-->Requirements-->System Hardware Requirements -->Processor -->AllProcessors/AnyOS
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that a  64-bit MSI cannot be installed on a 32-bit OS. This is a good summary:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

This too:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

So you need a 64-bit MSI for 64-bit systems (and this package can contain 32-bit components) and a 32-bit MSI for 32-bit systems (which cannot contain any 64-bit components).

Note that AnyCpu and its variations apply to your code, not to MSI setups.